# SSRS report error - .tvf function has too many arguments specified

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-tablix, table-valued-parameters

I am updating an existing code, by changing old parameters to the new ones:

```
      @RegionsWHID -  updated with @GLProgramGroupsWHID
      @ProgramsWHID - updated with @GLProgramsWHID  

      and added one more - @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID.
```

On previous updates (on the other codes - without the table-valued functions) - everything worked good.
But I am having the following error on this code, in SSRS reporting:
[image]

My code works fine in sql (SSMS), but shows an error in SSRS only
Here is the code:

```
   USE WH

      DECLARE @FYMonthBOP date = '07-01-2017'
      DECLARE @FYMonthEOP date = '03-31-2018'
      DECLARE @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID int = -1
      DECLARE @GLProgramGroupsWHID int = -1
      DECLARE @GLProgramsWHID_Groups int = -1

     SELECT        
            trans.GLGroupLevel0Name
          , trans.GLGroupLevel0Ordinal AS Ordinal0
          , trans.GLGroupLevel1Name
          , trans.GLGroupLevel1Ordinal AS Ordinal1
          , trans.GLGroupLevel2Name
          , trans.GLGroupLevel2Ordinal AS Ordinal2
          , trans.GLAccountCode
          , trans.GLAccountName
      --  , trans.Region
          , trans.GroupName
          , trans.GroupNameWHID
          , trans.OrdinalGroupName 
          , trans.GLProgramCode + N' ' + trans.GLProgramName AS Program
          , trans.FYQuarterLabel AS FQ
          , trans.AmountActual AS AmountActual
          , trans.AmountBudget
      --  , trans.[GLRegionFK] AS WHIDRegion
      --  , trans.RegionOrdinal AS OrdinalRegion
          , trans.GroupSetName
          , trans.GroupSetNameWHID
          , trans.[GLProgramFK] AS WHIDProgram
          , trans.ProgramOrdinal AS OrdinalProgram
          , trans.FYMonthNumber
          , trans.FYMonthShortLabel
          , trans.FYQuarterNumber
          , trans.FYNumber
          , trans.FYLabel
          , trans.YearMonthSort
          , IIF(EOMonth(mm.DateThru) < @FYMonthEOP, 
                EOMonth(mm.DateThru), @FYMonthEOP) AS [DateThru]

     FROM            
           [Reports].[tvfGLTransMonthlyActualBudget] 
            (@FYMonthBOP, @FYMonthEOP, @GLProgramGroupSetsWHID, 
             @GLProgramGroupsWHID, @GLProgramsWHID_Groups, 'Original') trans

      CROSS APPLY (
                    SELECT MAX(t.EffectiveMonth) AS [DateThru] 
                    FROM [Fact].[GLTransactionsMonthly] t WITH (NoLock) 
                  ) mm

      WHERE (
               (NOT (trans.[GLAccountCode] IN (N'9040',N'9047',N'4130'))) 

                AND (
                    (trans.[GLProgramFK] IN (
                           SELECT DISTINCT 
                                          f.[GLProgramFK]

                            FROM            
                                 [Fact].[GLTransactionsMonthly] f
                              INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] a 
                                      ON f.GLAccountFK = a.[WHID]

                                   WHERE 
                                       (f.EffectiveMonth BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP 
                                                            AND @FYMonthEOP)
                                   AND (a.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '5000' 
                                                                 AND '9999')

                                   GROUP BY
                                         f.[GLProgramFK]

                                         HAVING 
                                               (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0.0)
                                                                      ))
                                             OR
                                               (trans.[GLProgramFK] IN (
                                                  SELECT DISTINCT
                                                        f.[GLProgramFK]

                                                   FROM            
        [Fact].[GLTransactionsMonthly] f
        INNER JOIN [Dimension].[GLAccount] a ON f.GLAccountFK = a.[WHID]

    WHERE 
        (f.EffectiveMonth BETWEEN @FYMonthBOP AND @FYMonthEOP)
        AND (a.[GLAccountCode] BETWEEN '4000' AND '4999')

    GROUP BY
         f.[GLProgramFK]

    HAVING 
        (SUM(f.[Amount]) <> 0.0)
    ))
OR 
    (trans.[GLProgramCode] IN ('549'))
)
```

)

The error refers to the function - after the 1st FROM -
 **[Reports].[tvfGLTransMonthlyActualBudget]**
Everything else after this function remains untouched no needed to change

This is my table-valued function in SSMS:

[image]

The last argument - @BudgetVersion (circled in blue) - is not among my SSRS parameters.

Could this be the reason of error?

But, if -yes, - How come this report worked with the old parameters - @RegionsWHID and ProgramsWHID? In that version - SSRS also had no @BudgetVersion parameter...

Any suggestions or advice - would be a great help!

Thank you

Comment: The errors is because there are ***too many*** arguments supplied. The *real* TVF therefor has *less parameter* than believed (as 6 are supplied, unless that's incorrect..). Thus, the [definition of the invoked] function is *not* that of the function [definition] shown. -- Maybe refresh the UI display? Check the schema and/or connection? Try to invoke the ITVF with 6 parameters in a normal SSMS session?

Comment: Verify that the Data Source of the report points to the correct database (`WH`). I have seen a slimilar problem in SSIS, so also try to declare a variable in the dataset Code before the `SELECT` statement: `DECLARE @BudgetVersion nvarchar(30) = N'Original'` and use this variable in the function call instead of the constant value.

Comment: also your SQL datatypes don't match the functions declared datatypes.